# Php Box/Spout Format cell to currency and set width

Tags: php

After looking over the documentation for Box/Spout I do not see a way to format cells for currency.

NOTE: PhpExcel and PhpSpreadsheet are not an option.

Is there a way to format a cell?

While styling, is there a way to set the width of the cells?

This is my code so far.
It works, but is lacking currency formatting and width:

```
$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX); // for XLSX files
$writer->openToFile($tmpfile); // write data to a file or to a PHP stream
$writer_sheet = $writer->getCurrentSheet();

$writer_sheet->setName($invoiceSheetName);
$headerStyle = (new StyleBuilder())
  ->setFontBold()
  ->setFontUnderline()
  ->build();

// add header with style
$writer->addRowWithStyle($header, $headerStyle);

$writer->addRows($resultsArray); // add multiple rows at a time
$writer->close();
$excelOutput = file_get_contents($tmpfile);
```

Documentation:
[Spout Documentation](http://opensource.box.com/spout/docs/)

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: well if the documentation does not give the option .....

Comment: if its not possible with the code, and you cant use other code, what did you expect?

Comment: "I want to use function X to do something i know function X cant do", now what kind of question is that?

Comment: Where does it say it can't do it?  Look at the issues in their github repo. It can do it. There are pull requests that have some of these desired results implemented already. But, looks like they haven't been merged to master yet.  Why don't you explain why you think "it can't do it"?

Comment: "After looking over the documentation for Box/Spout I do not see a way to format cells for currency. " you obviously mean something different from how I interpreted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to implement my own implementation with unzipping the xlsx file and modifying the correct xml file.

Comment: Good! Spout does not support setting cell type/width as of now. There are a lot of gotchas implementing such a lib but if your use case is simple and in a controlled environment, building a minimalist product is fine.

Comment: @Drew you used the Spout or another lib?

Comment: How did you do it? It'd be nice if you could share.